# different types of scripting in linux

Tags: python, linux, perl, scripting

I am very new to linux, and i want to learn scripting. It seems like there are quite a few options to learn about scripting from bash shell scripting, python, perl lisp, and probably more that i dont know about. I am just wonder what are the  the advantage and disadvantage of all of them, and what would be a good place to start?

Comment: As much as I enjoy scripting, this is too broad a question.

Comment: sorry about that. just looking for a good place to start learning about scripting.

Comment: I agree, this is too broad a question. It's like asking somebody what are the advantages and disadvantages of a screwdriver compared to a motorized power drill compared to a wrench.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the long run? If you can give us your specific goals and aim then we probably could give you a better answer.

Comment: Yup, definitely too broad. You would be probably better off reading some reviews of the options you have in mind and decide which is best for what you want to do.

Comment: If you want to learn, start with Python, then maybe try Shell. After that go to perl and lisp, and then try other programming languages like C++ and Java! :)

Comment: Python, Perl and Lisp are full-fledged programming languages, not merely scripting languages.

Answer (score 5):

The most basic form of scripting is a Bourne shell script.  This can be as simple as multiple commands put in a file, one command per line.

```
# simple shell script example
clear
ls
```

This is an example program that clears the terminal screen, then lists the files in the current directory.  For this example, a shell script is by far the easiest way to do it.

In my experience, once Bourne shell scripts gain a bunch of features, they become very difficult to maintain.  Also, if you ever need to work with filenames or directory names that can contain spaces, it is very painful to properly quote your variables so that the script works correctly.  A more modern scripting language then becomes a boon.

My personal choice is Python.  It's easy to learn, and you will never find that it is not powerful enough for any problem.  You will also find that six months after writing a Python script, you will still be able to see what it does without needing to concentrate furiously and reverse-engineer the code in your head.

I recommend you find a good book, and read it and do the exercises.  If you use a Python book you will start with Python; if you get an advanced UNIX book it will teach you shell scripting.

Answer (score 2):

Every programmer will have a biased answer to this, but one thing to keep in mind is what your goal is.  For instance, if you're only looking to be a successful sysadmin, then your goals might best be served by learning languages that are more conducive to sysadmin tasks (e.g. bash).  However, if you're looking to do more general programming, including data analysis, you might be better served focusing your study on more general-purpose languages like Python or Perl.  For web development, Ruby might be worth studying, etc.   It really depends on why you're interested in learning scripting.

If you don't really have a specific reason and are looking for general advice, it's probably wise to start with one language and get proficient at it and then expand to other languages.  The canonical path would probably be bash --> Python, these days.   Of course, this is just one person's opinion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of times, people new to programming see all the options out there and don't know where to start.  You listed a bunch of different languages in your post.  My advice would be to pick one of those languages and find a book or tutorial and work through it.

I became interested in "scripting" from just trying to come up with a mIRC script that would fit my needs; however, after completing that, I changed OS from windows to Linux and mIRC scripting no longer would work for me.  So I started playing with Perl and Python to see which would work best for xChat.

Eventually, what it all boils down with is that you'll need to experiment with a language and do some hands on learning.  I eventually completed project, and used PHP for it. While completing that, I also was working through Michael Hartl's tutorial and worked with Ruby on Rails some.  Now I'm in the process of rewriting it using Node.js (javascript).

Best bet, just pick one language and start playing with it.